# How to insert asc/desc in addParameter for sorting in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this code

*dBCommand.AddParameter("@SORT", **"asc"**);*

Below is my query.

```
 SELECT TOP(1) RECEIPTID [RECEIPTID], TRANSTIME [TRANSTIME] FROM RetailTransactionTable
    WHERE TRANSDATE = @TRANSDATE 
    AND RECEIPTID != ''
    AND STORE = @STORE
    AND TERMINAL = @TERMINAL
    ORDER BY TRANSTIME @SORT
```

How can I place an asc and desc in AddParameter? Because it throws an error I guess because it is not in the right format?

Comment: You can't do that - modify query instead.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic sql to do this.

Comment: Any other workaround that is close to that code? I just wanna replace that @SORT. because I wanna order by asc and desc.

Comment: Maybe I should make  2 queries that have asc and desc.

Comment: You could use two queries and an IF statement. But be careful, that can lead some performance issues. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the query, you have an if statement which orders the results based on the @sort parameter value.

something like:

```
if @sort = 'ascending'
    select ... order by transtime asc
else
    select ... order by transtime desc
```

Comment: it doesn't look like a stored proc to me... but: the exact same approach could be used with/without stored proc

Answer (score 1):

The sort direction is part of the query itself and cannot be parameterized. You would need to either construct the query to embed `ASC` or `DESC` into the SQL (essentially `string.Format` or concatenation, but just of the `ASC`/`DESC` part - not of the input values), or have 2 different completed queries that you issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunately not possible. You can set if-else structure to handle this issue like:

```
if(orderParameter == "asc")
{
 SELECT TOP(1) RECEIPTID [RECEIPTID], TRANSTIME [TRANSTIME] FROM RetailTransactionTable
 WHERE TRANSDATE = @TRANSDATE 
 AND RECEIPTID != ''
 AND STORE = @STORE
 AND TERMINAL = @TERMINAL
 ORDER BY TRANSTIME ASC
}
else
{
 SELECT TOP(1) RECEIPTID [RECEIPTID], TRANSTIME [TRANSTIME] FROM RetailTransactionTable
 WHERE TRANSDATE = @TRANSDATE 
 AND RECEIPTID != ''
 AND STORE = @STORE
 AND TERMINAL = @TERMINAL
 ORDER BY TRANSTIME DESC
}
```

Or you can use String.Format(..) to set your query like

```
string orderParameter = "asc";
string sql = String.Format("SELECT TOP 1 RECEIPTID [RECEIPTID], TRANSTIME [TRANSTIME] 
               FROM RetailTransactionTable
               WHERE TRANSDATE = @TRANSDATE 
               AND RECEIPTID != ''
               AND STORE = @STORE
               AND TERMINAL = @TERMINAL
               ORDER BY TRANSTIME {0}",orderParameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

If by chance `TRANSTIME` has a datatype of `datetime` you can convert to a float and then apply a factor.

**HOWEVER**, I suspect a conditional approach would be more performant.

```
  SELECT TOP(1) RECEIPTID [RECEIPTID], TRANSTIME [TRANSTIME] FROM RetailTransactionTable
    WHERE TRANSDATE = @TRANSDATE 
    AND RECEIPTID != ''
    AND STORE = @STORE
    AND TERMINAL = @TERMINAL
    ORDER BY convert(float,TRANSTIME) * IIF(@Sort='asc',1,-1)
```